# Does $f(z)=z+2\bar z$ give a new complex structure on $\mathbb C$?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Define the map
$$f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C,$$
$$z\mapsto z+2\bar z,$$
and let $\omega=f(z)$ be the coordinate of the latter $\mathbb C$, clearly $f$ is a diffeomorphic map, but $f$ is not holomorphic, does it mean $f$ induces two different complex structures on the same underlying real manifold $\mathbb R^2$?

This question originates from the question about [deformations of complex torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705783/torus-t-2-as-a-deformation-of-t-1).

Comment: Do you know the Riemann mapping theorem, or more generally, the uniformization of Riemann surfaces? This tells you that there are only two complex structures on $\mathbb R^2$, up to biholomorphic maps. Namely $\mathbb C$ and the unit disc $D \subset \mathbb C$.

Comment: @red_trumpet, yes, I konw the Riemann mapping theorem, that's why I feel puzzled, I don't know where these two viewpoints contradict.

Comment: The two view points do not contradict at all, since for the "new" complex structure on $\mathbb C$, the map $f$ is a biholomorphism to the standard structure on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @AndreasCap, I guess the main point lies in the definition of complex structure, the "correct" definition is: if $X$ diffeomorphic to $Y$, but there is no biholomorphic map between them, then we say they have different complex structures; but here my definition may be stated as for the two coordinates $(z,\bar z), (\omega,\bar\omega)$ of $\mathbb C$, if $\frac{\partial\omega}{\partial \bar z}\ne 0$, then we say they have different complex structures, I think I should try to corret my definition to the ture one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you provided two different complex structures on $\mathbb R^2$. There is no doubt about that. You also gave a biholomorphic map to $\mathbb C$ for both structures (because you used those maps to define the complex structures, they have to be holomorphic). So they are isomorphic, but not the same.

I have the feeling you are more confused about uniformization? Maybe the following basic analogy from topology can help solve a bit of the confusion:

*Exercise*. On the set $\{a,b\}$ there are two different topologies where exactly one point is closed. Both define homeomorphic topological spaces.

Comment: Your example seems quite interesting, you mean the set $\{a,b\}$ have two different topologies which are homeomorphic to each other, in this sense, two different topologies are the same. As in my case, I have given two different complex structures which are biholomorphic to each other, so they are the "same" complex structure?  But what's the Beltrami differential $\varphi$ (see Morrow & Kodaira p.150) between them?

Comment: @Tom I'm not familiar with the term Beltrami differential, but if it helps the biholomorphic map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is given by $(x,y) \mapsto (3x, -y)$.

Comment: @Tom p.150 of *Complex Manifolds* by Morrow and Kodaira deals with something about deformations, that doesn't seem to fit here? Anyway, if you have follow up questions, it is always better to post them as new questions, instead of discussing in the comments section.

Comment: Ok, I will put it in another question, thanks for your suggestion and this nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

If $M$ is a manifold and $J$ and $J'$ are two complex structures on $M$ we say a map $f : (M,J) \to (M,J')$ is holomorphic if $df \circ J = J' \circ df$.
In your case we have $M = \mathbb R^2$ and
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
The set of complex structures on $\mathbb R^2$ is the set of matrices
$$
J' = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & -a \end{pmatrix}
$$
such that $a^2 + bc = -1$. In $(x,y)$ coordinates we have
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0
\\
0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Writing out the conditions for this to be holomorphic we get that $J'$ must satisfy
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -3 \\ -2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
= df \circ J
= J' \circ df
= \begin{pmatrix}
3a & -2b \\ 3c & -2a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $f$ is holomorphic if we give the second copy of $\mathbb R^2$ the complex structure
$$
J' =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 3/2 \\ -2/3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Like red_trumpet and Andreas pointed out, $(\mathbb R^2, J')$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C$ (via $f^{-1}$).

Comment: Dear Magnússon, nice to see you and your user-friendly answer again! Can you give a reference for a map $f : (M,J) \to (M,J')$ to be holomorphic? Cause I can't find it in Demailly or Huybrechts' books easily, and why $J$ can be written as $(0,-1;1,0)$?

Comment: I think Huybrechts talks about this in chapters 1.2 and 2.6, it's fairly standard. The keywords you're looking for are "almost complex structure". They usually come up in deformation theory or in pseudoholomorphic curves.

Comment: Tom, note that the standard complex structure on $\Bbb C$ (rotation by $\pi/2$) sends $\partial/\partial x$ to $\partial/\partial y$ and $\partial/\partial y$ to $-\partial/\partial x$. This matrix is the standard matrix of that linear map.