# Torus $T_2$ as a deformation of $T_1$.

Tags: complex-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $\mathbb C$ be the complex plane, the lattice $\Lambda_1=\mathbb Z+i\mathbb Z$ is spanned by two vectors $1,i$, and $\Lambda_2=\mathbb Z+2i\mathbb Z$ by $1,2i$. Then tori $T_1=\mathbb C/\Lambda_1$ and $T_2=\mathbb C/\Lambda_2$ have different complex structures (since they correspond to different points in the fundamental domain), although they are diffeomorphic.

By lifting $T_1$ and $T_2$ to $\mathbb C$, there is a diffeomorphic map
$$f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C,$$
$$(z,\bar z)\mapsto (w,\bar w)$$
which sends $1$ to $1$ and $i$ to $2i$, where $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$, then we get $x=u$ and $2y=v$, so $f$ can be written as $w=\frac{3}{2}z-\frac{1}{2}\bar z$, and the Jacobian matrix can be written as
$$
J=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}&\frac{\partial w}{\partial \bar z}\\
\frac{\partial \bar w}{\partial z}&\frac{\partial \bar w}{\partial \bar z}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{3}{2}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
then according to Kodaira (see Morrow & Kodaira's book *Complex manifolds* p.151, Prop 1.2), the complex structure of $T_2$ can be represented by a Beltrami differentail $\varphi\in A^{0,1}(X,T^{1,0}_X)$, where $\varphi$ can be written as $=\varphi^i_{\bar j}d\bar z^j\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial z^i}$ locally. And in our case $\varphi=\varphi^1_{\bar 1}d\bar z\otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, where
$\varphi^1_{\bar 1}=\frac{\frac{\partial w}{\partial \bar z}}{\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}}=-\frac{1}{3}$ (see M&K p.150, line 8 for definition) which is not $0$, so $T_2$ and $T_1$ have different complex structures according to Kodaira's deformation theory.

What I feel puzzled is that: why diffeomorphism $f$ induces two different complex structures on the same real manifold underlying both $T_1$ and $T_2$, but does not induce different complex structures on $\mathbb C$ (see my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704157/does-fz-z2-bar-z-give-a-new-complex-structure-on-mathbb-c/4704496?noredirect=1#comment9961858_4704496))?

My initial mativation is to understand the statement "the complex structure on $X_t$ is represented by $\varphi(t)$", so I represent the complex structure on $T_2$ relative to $T_1$ by $\varphi=-\frac{1}{3}d\bar z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, it is not zero, so they have different complex structures, till now, everything seems good? but when I represent the complex structures of $\mathbb C$ also by $\varphi$, some problems occur, we also have non-zero $\varphi=-\frac{1}{3}d\bar z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ for $\mathbb C$, it seems $f$ induces two differet complex structures on $\mathbb C$ as well, but it is not the case, I know I must have taken something wrong, but I don't know from which step, I made the mistake, can someone help me find the bug?

Comment: It is because of the fundamental group. But it is unclear to me what do you have a problem with: do you want to understand proofs of equivalence and nonequivalence?

Comment: @MoisheKohan, what do you mean by "it is because of the fundamental group"? I don't see any difference on fundamental group between $T_1$ and $T_2$, or $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C$, I want to understand why the difference of complex structures can not be represented by $\varphi$ on the $\mathbb C$ case, while it holds on the $T_1$ and $T_2$ case, see my later editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I feel puzzled is that: why diffeomorphism $f$ induces two different complex structures on the same real manifold underlying both $T_1$ and $T_2$, but does not induce different complex structures on $\mathbb C$

Well, it does. Your map $$f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, \quad x+iy \mapsto x + 2 iy$$ is not holomorphic with respect to the standard complex structure on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: When I see "it does", I feel a sense of relief, but after a while, I realized the problem becomes: then why in the $\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R^2$) case, two complex structures are isomorphic, while in the torus case, these two complex structures can not be make isomorphic to each other.

Comment: @Tom The reason is that any biholomorphic map $\bar f: T_1 \to T_2$ would induce a biholomorphic map $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ (because $\mathbb C \to T_i$ is a universal covering, and being holomorphic is a local property), such that $f$ identifies the two lattices. Such a thing does not exist. So either $f$ is not holomorphic (as in your example), or it doesn't identify the lattices, then $\bar f:T_1 \to T_2$ cannot be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want to see. I have understood why $T_1$ can't  be biholomorphic to $T_2$, but it seems to me: for the $\mathbb C$ case, two complex structures are not "=", but "$\cong$"; while for the torus case, $T_1$ and $T_2$ not only are not "=", but also do not "$\cong$", but if $\mathbb C$ is equipped with a "new" complex structure $w=u+iv=x+i2y$, then $T_2$ seems isomorphic to $T_1$?

Comment: @Tom Well yeah, if you also give $T_2$ the corresponding complex structure which comes from the diffeomorphism $T_1 \to T_2$.

Comment: If everything is considered in this way, then it seems no contradictions will appear, it seems to me if we define 1 meter to be 2 meters long, then every physical formula are isomorphic to the other, but they are not equal.